# Elements of pandas covariance matrix greater than 1

Tags: python, pandas

I'm calculating the covariance matrix of some time-series data with pandas as such:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('stocks.dat', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
data.columns = ['s1', 's2', 's3']

print(data.cov())
```

But this is the output:

```
             s1            s2         s3
s1   470.117981   1862.176032  -4.161120
s2  1862.176032  11349.608303 -22.609931
s3    -4.161120    -22.609931   5.928825
```

The numbers have magnitude greater than one! But the definition of covariance is that it ranges between -1 and 1! Either I have a big misunderstanding or pandas is doing something weird! What's going on, and how can I get the covariance matrix I expect?

The data looks like this:

```
165.82  2612.6  41.46
163.98  2605    41.876
165.26  2640.9  41.982
164.18  2581.9  41.248
165.86  2614.4  41.934
```

Comment: I think you are mistaken correlation for covariance. There's no reason for covariance to be between -1 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.corr()` is the correct syntax to produce (Pearson) correlation between each pair of columns.